# Search result display

Tags: php, magento

Hi I’m trying to display the search result sorted by attribute_set_id. I want to display them as title of the first attribute_set name and then products that’s belong to attribute_set_id 1 and then title of attribute_set 2 and then the products in attribute set 2

Any one got an idea on how i can make this happened ?

I have tried to sort the result list by the following code

```
    <?php $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

    $_productCollection->clear()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('attribute_set_id', 'DESC')
        ->load();
    ?>
```

Comment: This is a great question, however I think it's more suited to http://magento.stackexchange.com/?as=1 since the question is a tad localized for those who know PHP, but not Magento Objects ..

Comment: @Zak Initial idea behind magento.stackexchange.com was only admin/user/none-programmatic questions that can't be asked and answered here, so this question suits SO perfectly, but not SE. However it seems that SE site became everything Magento-related :)

Comment: @SergeiGuk I will agree to that, being that the original intent of the SE site was for Magento-esk questions that are non-programming related, although, there is more of a need for programmers to have a knowledge base than GUI admins ...  I suppose that's why it's essentially been "converted" to a Mage programmers forum ..

Answer (score 0):

If you receive your collection and just can't sort it, try to use `->setOrder('attribute_set_id', 'DESC')` because ->addAttributeToSort applies to EAV types only

`setOrder($field, $direction = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)` is from Varien/Data/Collection.php so should work fine